# Setting deployment synchronizer for WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 worker node

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to setup WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 cluster using the Manager/Worker deployment pattern following [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer).

I managed to set up successfully the deployment synchronizer for the manager node. However when I start the worker node using the option "-DworkerNode=true", I get the following error:

```
[2016-02-02 19:07:07,577] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerComponent} -  Error while initializing a deployment synchronizer for the super tenant Carbon repository
org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.DeploymentSynchronizerException: No Repository found for type svn
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.getDeploymentSyncConfigurationFromConf(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.getActiveSynchronizerConfiguration(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.repository.CarbonRepositoryUtils.isSynchronizerEnabled(CarbonRepositoryUtils.java:239)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.initDeploymentSynchronizerForSuperTenant(DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.activate(DeploymentSynchronizerComponent.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

If I started the same node with "-DworkerNode=false" no error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 IS 5.1.0 doesn't need the worker/manager separation. For further details read [1] and [2].

Thanks.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Separating+the+Worker+and+Manager+Nodes

Comment: I missed the "tip" in the documentation that says that WSO2 IS 5.1.0 doesn't need the worker/manager separation. Thanks!